# Automating chunking of big data in R using a loop

Tags: r, chunking

I am trying to break a very large dataset into chunks. I my code looks like this:

```
#Chunk 1
data <- read.csv("/Users/admin/Desktop/data/sample.csv", header=T, nrow=1000000)
write.csv(data, "/Users/admin/Desktop/data/data1.csv")

#Chunk 2
data <- read.csv("/Users/admin/Desktop/data/sample.csv", header=F, nrow=1000000, skip=1000000)
write.csv(data, "/Users/admin/Desktop/data/data2.csv")

#Chunk 3
data <- read.csv("/Users/admin/Desktop/data/sample.csv", header=F, nrow=1000000, skip=2000000)
write.csv(data, "/Users/admin/Desktop/data/data3.csv")
```

There are hundreds of millions of rows in my dataset, so I need to create a lot of chunks, and I would really like to automate the process.  Is there a way to loop this command so that each subsequent chunk automatically skips 1,000,000 more rows than the previous chunk did, and the file saves as "dataN.csv" (N symbolizing the subsequent number from that of the previous file)?

Comment: Sure: have you tried [writing a for loop](http://paleocave.sciencesortof.com/2013/03/writing-a-for-loop-in-r/)?

Comment: Try the LaF package and in particuldar read the blockwise processing section of its vignette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following way? For the demonstration I created a data frame with two columns and ten lines and read it within a loop two times, each time five lines, saving the result as a text file:

```
f<-"C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/"
for(i in 1:2){
    df <- read.table("C:/Users/MyPC/Desktop/df.txt", header=FALSE, nrow=5, skip=5*(i-1))
    file <- paste(f,sep="","df",i,".txt")
    write.table(df,file)
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and I got the following error message: `Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, na.strings = character(0L)) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<c9><fa><d2><e2><bb><ef><b0><e9><c1><f7>'`

Comment: What kinds of columns does your dataset consist of? Can you provide `str(dataset)`?

Comment: The first version was not really what you asked for. Try the editted version.

Answer (score 1):

A few improvements on the answers above. Instead of a for loop, use lapply() and instead of read.table(), use data.table::fread().

**For loop vs. lapply** 
It has been well documented that, if possible, one should use lapply instead of a for loop. A quick Google search will show plenty of arguments and examples to that effect. lapply is faster, it returns a list instead of one having to define a list (or other storage object), and it can be easily run in parallel because each iteration of the loop is an independent function call, not a loop on the "top level." In this case, switching to lapply saves 7 seconds (which is rather trivial but it is better to get into good habits).

**read.csv() vs data.table::fread()**
fread() is a major speed improvement over read.csv() (I've seen 2-5x speedups, depending on the data, etc. [here](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/09/03/handling-big-data-in-r/) is an article that shows a ~15x speedup) and it was designed to handle some administrative tasks like guessing the delimiter. In this case, there is a 15 second speedup when exchanging fread() for read.csv()

```
> # Libraries and options ---------------------------------------------------
> 
> library(dplyr)

> library(data.table)

> # Helper parameters -------------------------------------------------------
> 
> out_dir = "C:/Users/taylor/Dropbox/R_programming/stackoverflow/data"

> obs = 5e5 

> # Create test data --------------------------------------------------------
> 
> test_df = data_frame(
+   x = rnorm(obs), 
+   y = 0.5 * obs + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.25), 
+   groups = rep(letters[1:5], length.out = length(x))
+ )

> # export
> write.csv(test_df, paste0(out_dir, "/test_df.csv"), row.names = F)

> # clean memory
> rm(test_df)

> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells  596408 31.9    1907703 101.9  10636178  568.1
Vcells 9301642 71.0   27768113 211.9 218137457 1664.3

> # For loop and read.csv (read.table alias) -------------------------------------
> 
> system.time({
+   
+   for(i in 1:20){  
+     df = read.csv(paste0(out_dir, "/test_df.csv"))
+     write.csv(df, paste0(out_dir, "/test_df_export_original_example_", i, ".csv"), row.names = F)  
+   }  
+   
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
 130.28    2.70  148.60 

> # Lapply and read.csv -----------------------------------------------------
> 
> # clean memory
> rm(df, i)

> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells  596411 31.9    2185242 116.8  10636178  568.1
Vcells 9301647 71.0   27768113 211.9 218137457 1664.3

> system.time({
+   
+   lapply(1:20, function(i){
+     df = read.csv(paste0(out_dir, "/test_df.csv"))
+     write.csv(df, paste0(out_dir, "/test_df_export_lapply_", i, ".csv"), row.names = F)  
+   })  
+   
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
 123.33    2.07  140.03 

> # Lapply and fread() ------------------------------------------------------
> 
> system.time({
+   
+   lapply(1:20, function(i){
+     df = fread(paste0(out_dir, "/test_df.csv"))
+     write.csv(df, paste0(out_dir, "/test_df_export_lapply_fread_", i, ".csv"), row.names = F)  
+   })  
+   
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
 107.98    2.10  123.36
```

Comment: Could you expand this answer with an example, and why it might be an improvement over the first answer?

Comment: @alexforrence edits made. It really doesn't make sense to be so nitpicky -- why should I spend an extra 20 minutes of my life perfecting an answer when someone can take 5 minutes to Google fread vs. read.table or lapply vs for loops after receiving advice to that effect?

Comment: Essentially, answers should be able to stand on their own. See the answers [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276728/2690232) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285728/2690232) for related discussion.